# Javascript to make the size of my background image match my window size

Tags: javascript, background

When I load my web page, I want my background image to exactly match my window size.  I have the following code.  It is giving me an error: `$("body") is null`.   The page loads and the background has an image, however, the background is not the correct size.

```
  function resizeFrame() 
  {
      alert("resizeFrame");
      var h = window.screen.height;
      var w = window.screen.width;
      $('body').css('background-size', w + 'px ' + h + 'px' );
  }
```

What is the correct way to resize my background image in this javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the code to resize in `$(function() { })`. This will ensure the DOM is ready to be modified before your code executes.

```
$(function() {
   $(window).resize(function() {
       $('body').css('background-size', $(this).width() + 'px ' + $(this).height() + 'px');
   });
});
```

You should just be able to use CSS...

```
body {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Assuming your `body` element is defined to fill the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

call the function after page loading completed.

```
$(document).ready({
    resizeFrame() 
});
```